# AngularJS ng-repeat in modal

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have problem - i want to show details of one person in modal when i click on the button in table. But i have details of everyone.
My code:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Details</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <ul ng-repeat="person in people">

                    <li> {{person.details}}</li>

                </ul>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<table>
    <thead style="background-color: lightgray;">
        <tr>

            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Gender</td>
            <td>Details</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="person in people">

            <td>{{person.name}}</td>
            <td>{{person.gender}}</td>
            <td>
                <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" title="Layers" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

My plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/g1t4pludTTIAJYKTToCK?p=preview

Thanks for answers in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are displaying each person's detail with ngRepeat change that and display single person detail for reference see this:

http://plnkr.co/edit/CLMjfcAhNibJugivRw8N?p=preview

In modal do as :

```
 <div class="modal-body">
       <li> {{person.details}}</li>                            
 </div>
```

In script add :

```
   $scope.showDetails = function(person){
            $scope.person = person;
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
```

And call above function as :

```
  <button ng-click="showDetails(person)" title="Layers" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger" ></span></button>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to add `ng-repeat` in modal template.
Also you are using jquery Bootstrap modal popup which is not recommended in angularjs.

Refer this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/13962/) link.
I have updated all your code with solution in this fiddle.
I have removed jquery bootstrap and used angular ui bootstrap in angular way

Added following code :

```
<button ng-click="openModal(person)" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span></button>
```

see `ng-click` function and I am passing person (this object we get it from ng-repeat itself) object along with it and implemented as below :

```
$scope.openModal = function(person) {
    console.log(person)
    $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModal.html',
      backdrop: 'static',
      controller: ['$scope', '$modalInstance', '$timeout', function($scope, $modalInstance, $timeout) {
        $scope.personDetail = person.details;
        $scope.cancel = function() {
          $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
      }]

    });
  }
```

***Its highly recommended that you should use angular-ui-bootstrap rather than jquery bootstrap***